# initializing a map inside a for loop

Tags: c++

I am having a problem initializing a map. the goal is to use a string that contains all the keys .e.g "key1 key2 key3" to create entries in the map

```
map<const char *, int, ltstr > mymap;
string fortest="a b c";
istringstream iss(fortest);
string field;
//cout<<"transaction name:"<<transactionName<<'\n';
//cout<<"transaction fields:"<<'\n';
while(iss>>field)
{
    mymap[&field[0]]=0;
    cout<<"field name:"<<field<<'\n';
    cout<<mymap.size()<<'\n';
}
```

But this doesnt work. I am not sure what is the problem

Comment: Why would you use pointers as keys? `std::map<std::string, int>`.

Comment: Also, you forgot to explain what "this doesnt work" means for you...

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is you are adding a value into the map and then immediately changing it.  If you expand out the code you are essentially doing the following

```
iss >> field;
mymap[&field[0]] = 0;
iss >> field;  // Error!
mymap[&field[0]] = 0;
```

The labeled line is a problem because a member of `field` is stored as a key inside of `mymap`.  The 3rd line will mutate `field` which means the key within `mymap` is also mutated.  This type of behavior is not allowed, map types assume that their keys are immutable.  Mutating them makes it impossible to reliably retrieve the values later on

It looks like what you want to do is associate a string with an `int` in the map. If so then just use `std::string` as the key.

```
map<std::string, int, ltstr> mymap;
...
while (iss>>field) {
  mymap[field] = 0;
}
```

This will put an independent copy of the `std::string` in the map for every line.  Hence the mutations won't affect keys in the map.

Note: You will likely have to chang ltstr to take `const std::string&` as an input instead of `const char*` as well to make this workt

Also note that when you want to convert an `std::string` to a `const char*` don't use `&field[0]` but instead use the standard method `field.c_str()`.

Comment: Thanks Jared.. I see what the problem now

Comment: `ltstr` is almost certainly a wrapper around `strcmp`, so we shan't be in need of that any more with `std::string` keys. Also, `std::string::cstr()` does not exist.